# Problemas al realizar informe en sql developer

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente problema tengo un caso el cual me pide un informe con el nombre de cliente,nombre del contacto,total de compras,monto total de compras,valor promedio por compra,descuento aplicado y monto total pagado con la siguiente información.

El valor promedio por compra está basado en el monto total de las compras efectuadas y el total de las compras efectuadas.
Se aplica un descuento del 20% al monto total de las compras si el valor promedio por compra es superior a $1.000.000, en caso contrario el descuento equivale a un 10%.

mi query es la siguiente.

```
   select initcap(c.nombre_cli) as "CLIENTE",
   initcap(c.nombre_contacto) as "CONTACTO",
   count(b.nro_boleta) as "TOTAL COMPRAS",
   to_char(b.total,'$999g999g999') as "MONTO TOTAL COMPRAS",
   to_char(b.total/count(b.nro_boleta),'$999g999g999') as "VALOR PROMEDIO 
   POR COMPRA"
   from cliente c
   join orden o
   on(c.cliente_id = o.cliente_id)
   join boleta b
   on(o.orden_id = b.orden_id)
   group by c.nombre_cli,c.nombre_contacto,b.total
```

El caso es que me tiene que quedar de la siguiente forma o similar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad llevo bastante intentado lograr esta query pero no logro pasar ni del valor promedio agradeceria una ayuda muchas gracias.

aqui la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]